# conda list enviornment location not found

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

on windows 10:
Conda was working ok. However now I get the following:

```
$conda list:
 EviornmentLocationNotfound: not a conda environment:C:/users/xxx/anaconda3 
$conda --version:
conda 4.5.11:
$conda update numpy [or any package]:
 PackageNotInstalledError :package not installed in prefix:
$conda install or info or search seem to work fine:
```

Comment: Please send output of "conda info".  What is the value of "conda-build version" in the output?

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda a while ago so  the problem is resolved

Comment: You may write an answer to your question! Just mention that reinstalling solved the problem .